# Remove class from one div and add to another div in one click

Tags: jquery

I am using JQuery to make small images go bigger when clicked.

When the div containing a small image is clicked, JQuery assigns a class "figure_full_demo" that makes it expand - when the large image-container is clicked, the class is removed.

This works well even when the page contains several images. The problem occurs if a large image-container isnt clicked before clicking the next small container - then i have to double-click to make it expand.

How can i remove class 'figure_full_demo' from large image-container and add it to a small container in ONE click? 
Hope my question is clear - ill post some code:

```js
$('.figure').click(function() {  
  if ($('#wrapper').css('position') == 'relative'){
    $('#wrapper').css({'position':'static'});
    $('.figure').removeClass('figure_full_demo'); 
    $(this).addClass('figure_full_demo'); 
  }   
  else { 
    $('#wrapper').css({'position':'relative'});
    $('.figure').removeClass('figure_full_demo'); 
  } 
});
```

```css
#wrapper   { 
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 690px; 
  padding: 30px 12px 60px 12px; 
  margin: 0 auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 2px solid green;
}
.figure {
  border: 1px solid red; 
  cursor: pointer;
}
.figure_full_demo  {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 5000;
  left: 5%;
  right: 5%;
  width: 90%;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="figure"> 
    <img src="http://placehold.it/400x100/" alt="Pic 1">
  </div>

  <div class="figure"> 
    <img src="http://placehold.it/400x100/" alt="Pic 2">       
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would check if the user pressed the large container or small image:

```
$(this).hasClass('figure_full_demo')
```

instead of checking if there is a large container active

```
$('#wrapper').css('position') == 'relative'
```

Something like:

```
$('.figure').click(function() {     
  if ($(this).hasClass('figure_full_demo')){
    /* Large container clicked */      
    $('#wrapper').css({'position':'relative'});
    $('.figure').removeClass('figure_full_demo'); 
  } else {
    /* Small container clicked */      
    $('.figure').removeClass('figure_full_demo'); 
    $('#wrapper').css({'position':'static'});
    $(this).addClass('figure_full_demo'); 
  }
});
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/km1md66h/)

```js
$(document).ready(
  function() {
    $('.figure').click(function() {  
      if ($(this).hasClass('figure_full_demo')){
        /* Large container clicked */      
        $('#wrapper').css({'position':'relative'});
        $('.figure').removeClass('figure_full_demo'); 
      } else {
        /* Small container clicked */      
        $('.figure').removeClass('figure_full_demo'); 
        $('#wrapper').css({'position':'static'});
        $(this).addClass('figure_full_demo'); 
      }
    });
  }
);
```

```css
#wrapper   { 
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 690px; 
  padding: 30px 12px 60px 12px; 
  margin: 0 auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 2px solid green;
}
.figure {
  border: 1px solid red; 
  cursor: pointer;
}
.figure_full_demo  {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 5000;
  left: 5%;
  right: 5%;
  width: 90%;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="figure"> 
    <img src="http://placehold.it/400x100/&text=Pic+1" alt="Pic 1">
  </div>

  <div class="figure"> 
    <img src="http://placehold.it/400x100/&text=Pic+2" alt="Pic 2">       
  </div>
      
  <div class="figure"> 
    <img src="http://placehold.it/400x100/&text=Pic+3" alt="Pic 3">       
  </div>
      
  <div class="figure"> 
    <img src="http://placehold.it/400x100/&text=Pic+4" alt="Pic 4">       
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.not(this)` function in order to remove the class from every .figure element exept the one clicked

```
$('.figure').click(function() {     
    $('.figure').not(this).removeClass('figure_full_demo');
    if ($('#wrapper').css('position') == 'relative'){
            $('#wrapper').css({'position':'static'});
            $('.figure').removeClass('figure_full_demo'); 
            $(this).addClass('figure_full_demo'); 
    }   
    else { 
        $('#wrapper').css({'position':'relative'});
        $('.figure').removeClass('figure_full_demo'); 
    } 
});
```

Comment: Would be perfect, just without the .not(this) it is useless.

Comment: That doesnt change anything

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/h9vc3haw/3/

---

```
$('.figure').on("click", function(){        
    $('.figure').not(this).removeClass('figure_full_demo'); 
    $(this).toggleClass('figure_full_demo');
});
```

Comment: I know that number of lines isn't all.. but it looks nice and works very nice too... **note** that _position:static_ works better in css class _figure_full_demo_ instead of setting it in jquery